# Image Url In C#

Tags: c#

I am Using A Hard coded Image In My Web App When I Uploaded My Web App The Default Image Url IS

> http://localhost:61111/Images/blank_profile_female.jpg

But I want My Default Url As

```
..../Images/blank_profile_female.jpg
```

I did Something Like This

```
imgbx.ImageUrl = "http://localhost61111/Images/facebook-default-no-profile-pi‌​c.jpg";
```

Is It Possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what results did you get?

Comment: @Daniel I did Something Like This

`imgbx.ImageUrl = "http://localhost61111/Images/facebook-default-no-profile-pic.jpg";`

Comment: Just use `/Images/blank_profile_female.jpg`. As in `<img src="/Images/blank_profile_female.jpg"/>` This will be relative to your root. That said your question is unclear. What do you mean by default URL, etc?

Comment: Yes It Is Unclear I Should Not Use Default, Its Just The Url Of The Image

Answer (score 0):

For MVC application

```
Url.Content("~/Images/blank_profile_female.jpg")
```

For Web Application

```
Server.MapPath("~/Images/blank_profile_female.jpg");
```

Comment: I am Doing This Code In Back End

Comment: Is it a mvc application or simple web application?

Comment: Web Application